# Change pitch and sound levels of audio sources?

Tags: windows, audio, sound-card

I have an audio source in which people are having conversations and music is playing, but the pitch is very high.  It's grating and annoying to listen to their high-pitched voices.  Is it possible to lower the pitch of audio in Windows 10?  Enhancements are not available on my sound card for some reason.

Comment: I removed the off-topic software request, but that leaves a question missing some key information, which makes it too broad.  What software are you using to listen to the audio source?  What is the audio source?  What audio software do you have that might be a tool to do this that you don't know how to use to accomplish the task?  Asking how to accomplish this with specific software available to you would generally be on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do this natively in Windows 10 but you have some other options.

Wavelab for example does this, but that has a cost.

Audacity has plugins such as http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/change_pitch.html

There are websites such as http://onlinetonegenerator.com/pitch-shifter.html but you can use a search term similar to `change pitch of wav` and get [results](https://www.google.com/search?q=change+pitch+of+wav&oq=change+pitch+of+wav&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.2319j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: The official stance is to please refrain from answering off-topic questions, unless they warrant migration, in which case answer & vote or flag to migrate - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions It's harder to delete questions once they have an answer.